Не получается подобрать правильную кодировку в PostgreSQL
у меня такая проблема, мне нужно в postgreSQL сохранить русскоязычный текст со эмодзи и при попытке прочитать данные в бд выходят кракозябры, при этом кодировка стояла UTF 8 и я решил поменять её на windows 1251, но она не поддерживает эмодзи, какую мне тогда поставить кодировку?

Кодировка самой базы данных и кодировка того, чем вы её читаете, должна совпадать.
